# random variables being each others' distribution parameters

Tags: distributions, maximum-likelihood

Let $$Y_{t+1}|\mathcal{F}_t\sim\mathcal{D}_1(\mathcal{\Theta}_1(X_t,Y_t))$$ and $$X_{t+1}|\mathcal{F}_t\sim\mathcal{D}_2(\mathcal{\Theta}_2(X_t,Y_t))$$, where $\mathcal{\Theta}_i$ is function of random variables, say, $$\mathcal{\Theta}_1=\beta_1X_t+\beta_2X_{t-1}+\beta_3Y_t$$. Can I estimate the system using MLE equation by equation, i.e., do the optimization separately?

Edit: we observe $(X_t,Y_t)$ on a daily basis. Also I realize this is a bit like VAR. But don't expect it to be that simple. the distributions $D_i$ can be very complicated, such as non-central gamma.

Comment: It depends on what data you have.  For instance, when you have observations $(X_t,Y_t)$ at regularly spaced values of $t,$ you are working with a *vector time series,* for which there are (many) standard techniques.  But if you are in any other situation we need to know more details.  Please clarify.

Comment: To whuber: yes, I have daily observations of $(X_t,Y_t)$